# Identify renewals from downloaded Google Play reports

Tags: android, google-play

we use gsutil to download earnings/financial/sales/installs -reports from Google cloud for our Android app.

Is there any way to pinpoint annual renewal transactions for subscriptions  in the PlayApps or salesreports reports? Do they somehow differ from the regular charges?

Are annual renewals listed as New subscriptions in the subscriptions report?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question..

There is a recurrence id in the Order number for all recurrences of the subscription and denotes each recurring transaction by appending an integer